# Solving the recurrence $T(n) = 2^{n/2}T(n/2) + 2^n$ using a recursion tree

Tags: trees, recursion

I have homework from recursion tree and despite my search for hours I could not find the answer to this problem.

I appreciate if you can help.

> Draw a recursion tree and give a tight asymptotic bound on the solution of the recurrence $T(n) = 2^{n/2}T(n/2) + 2^n$. You need not prove your answer.

Comment: The way to find and answer to a problem is to try to solve it yourself!

Comment: Do you know what a recursion tree is?

Comment: In order to give you a helpful answer we need to know what you have tried and where, specifically, you got stuck.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate question, the word "tree" doesn't appear once in the linked question therefore whether or not the linked question answers general questions about asymptotic behavior it _does not_ give examples of using a recursion tree (which is a pretty standard technique).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a recursion tree is, but I know how to expand a formula:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= 2^{n/2} T(n/2) + 2^n \\ &=
2^{n/2} (2^{n/4}T(n/4) + 2^{n/2}) + 2^n \\ &=
2^{(3/4)n} T(n/4) + 2^n + 2^n \\ &=
2^{(3/4)n} (2^{n/8} T(n/8) + 2^{n/4}) + 2^n + 2^n \\ &=
2^{(7/8)n} T(n/8) + 2^n + 2^n + 2^n \\ &= \cdots
\end{align*}
$$
You take it from here, along the following lines:

1. Assume that $n$ is a power of $2$. How many times do we need to apply the recurrence identity until we get to $T(1)$? (Above I applied it three times and got down to $T(n/8)$.)
2. When we do get to $T(1)$, what are we left with? (When we get down to $T(n/8)$, we are left with $2^{(7/8)n} T(n/8) + 3\cdot 2^n$.)
3. Suppose that $T(1) = C$. Can you come up with a formula for $T(n)$? Can you deduce a tight asymptotic bound?